# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input at Object.parse (native) npm request

Tags: node.js, request

Hello I don't understand why I have this error, I thought the callback was executed once the data has been received, any idea where this come from ?
Thanks a lot!

Node error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
  at Object.parse (native)
```

I parse the body's answer send it to a calculate function before sending it to the page =/

```
var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: self.rippledataapiProxyHost.account_offers_exercised,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        },
        body:parameters 
    };

    var callback = function(error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('error', error);
            res.send(500, 'something went wrong');
        }
        console.dir("bodyyyyyyyy====>",body);
        var rippleoffersexercised = new self.datacalcul.rippleoffersexercised;
        var data = JSON.parse(body);
        var datas = rippleoffersexercised.calculate(data);
        res.status(response.statusCode).send(datas);
    }
    request(options, callback);
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
'bodyyyyyyyy====>'

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
  at Object.parse (native)
  at Request.callback [as _callback] (/home/francois/dev/ripplereport/webserver-newclientFrancois/server/middlewares/proxy/rippledataapiProxy.js:77:20)
  at Request.self.callback (/home/francois/dev/ripplereport/webserver-newclientFrancois/node_modules/request/request.js:344:22)
  at Request.emit (events.js:98:17)
  at Request.<anonymous> (/home/francois/dev/ripplereport/webserver-newclientFrancois/node_modules/request/request.js:1239:14)
  at Request.emit (events.js:117:20)
  at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/francois/dev/ripplereport/webserver-newclientFrancois/node_modules/request/request.js:1187:12)
  at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
  at _stream_readable.js:943:16
  at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)

[gulp] [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: What does `console.dir(body)` show?

Comment: it shows the object, this is weird this is working but sometimes it crashes can't tell why

Comment: `console.dir(body)` shows an *object*? It should show a string. You could try setting `json: true` in your request() options.

Comment: What is the actual stack trace? Is the error pointing to your `JSON.parse(body)` or is it coming from somewhere inside `.send(datas)` ?

Comment: So I guess it comes from the JSON.parse but why does it occurs sometimes only ? I have to send the request few times to reproduce the bug.

Comment: In your example, the body is empty. Empty input to `JSON.parse` triggers the `SyntaxError` as expected (you should catch that). The question is why you receive an empty body. Do you use that callback function for this route only? Chrome, for example, tends to prefetch urls which can lead to unexpected requests.

Comment: thank you chris I think this is unexpected empty body

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you are probably getting empty or malformed requests which cause the `JSON.parse` to throw. Something like this should help you:

```
var callback = function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
        console.log('error', error);
        return res.send(500, 'something went wrong');
    }
    try {
        var data = JSON.parse(body);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log('malformed request', body);
        return res.status(400).send('malformed request: ' + body);
    }
    console.log('body', body);
    var rippleoffersexercised = new self.datacalcul.rippleoffersexercised;
    var datas = rippleoffersexercised.calculate(data);
    return res.status(response.statusCode).send(datas);
}
```

Comment: the real problem was inside my calculate function, I was creating an object and working on fields that was being created (not created yet) so I resolved this using a promise. Your answer is a good tip anyway thank you.