# Parsing Unexpected End

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can someone please explain me why I am getting an issue with this one line because for some reason when I run it with node in the console I'm receiving the Unexpected end of input at Object.parse(native) response.

```
var profile = JSON.parse(body);
```

Full code:

```
//Problem: We need a simple way to look at a user's badge count and Javascript points
//Solution: Use Node.js to connect to Treehouse's API to get profile information to print out
var http = require("http");
var username = "testuser";

//Print out message
function printMessage(username, badgeCount, points) {
    var message = username + " has " + badgeCount + " total badge(s) and " + points + " points in Javascript";
    console.log(message);
}

//Print out error messages
function printError(error) {
    console.error(error.message);
}

//Connect to API URL (http://teamtreehouse.com/username.json)
var request = http.get("http://teamtreehouse.com/" + username + ".json", function(response) {
    var body = "";
    //Read the data
    response.on('data', function(chunk) {
        body += chunk;
    });
    response.on('end', function() {
        if(response.statusCode == 200){
            try {
                var profile = JSON.parse(body);
                printMessage(username, profile.badges.length, profile.points.Javascript);
            } catch(error) {
                //Parse Error
                printError(error);
            }
        } else {
            //Status Code Error
            printError({message: "There was an error getting the profile for " + username +".  (" + http.SSTATUS_CODES[response.statusCode] + ")"});
        }
    });
    //Parse the data
    //Print the data
});

//Connection Error
request.on('error', printError);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input at Object.parse (native) npm request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29259395/syntaxerror-unexpected-end-of-input-at-object-parse-native-npm-request)

Comment: Check out my edit because I don't see my problem.

Comment: Have you checked the JSON in the request?  Is it valid JSON?  Try using a browser's dev tools to copy the JSON in the response, then validate it with a JSON linter/validator.  `JSON.parse()` is very picky.

Comment: Since it does work then what could be the issue?

Comment: My mistake, it turns out it's valid JSON after all. But were you testing the 'test' username or another username? Because if you try it with a nonexistent username, then you get a 404 error...that could throw it off too.

Comment: I tested it with my actual screen name and it works.

Comment: Do you mean you tested that the JSON for your screen name is valid, or that you tested the above code with your screen name and it works, or both? My guess is it's working for some usernames but not others. If the server returned an empty string for some reason, that could case this error.

Comment: how should I test to verify i get what's expected.

Comment: There's a syntax error somewhere am I'm not seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

When I try to browse to http://teamtreehouse.com/test.json, it redirects me to the corresponding HTTPS url. Use the nodejs https module and use the https version of the url : https://teamtreehouse.com/test.json.

Or use the popular request module that can handle redirects and https : https://github.com/request/request. It is easier to use as well.