# Background polling AJAX requests leads to errors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, polling

I have a Javascript function foo that uses AJAX to request some data from my server. On success, it `setTimeout(foo, 5000)` to continue background calling.

However, it seems like after a while of keeping the tab open with no activity, an error is thrown. It's hard to reproduce and find what the actual error is, but it is the Ajax request throwing an error.

The code is written in a way that only 1 request is open at a time, so it can't be too many concurrent open requests. Is there possible some sort of limit on the total number of requests (not concurrent) in browsers? And after a long time with the tab open, that limit is reached?

Comment: Can you please share the error that you are receiving. Thanks.

Comment: I'd highly suggest posting some of your code here so we can get an idea of what you're trying to do, or what you may be doing wrong.

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Object.parse (native)` Maybe the browser is blocking the requests after a while?

Comment: ` function getData() {
$.ajax( .... success = function() {
        setTimeout(_.bind(this.getData, this), 5000); } ... )
`
This isn't the actual code so it's probably not syntactically correct, but that's the gist of how it works. And it does work when I try it, just after a while with the tab open cryptic errors occur.

Comment: According to a previous post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29259395/syntaxerror-unexpected-end-of-input-at-object-parse-native-npm-request , that error could imply that you may be receiving malformed data from the AJAX request. Could it be that your server side code is the problem rather than your client side JavaScript.